# Fit model to all variables in Python (Scikit Learn)

Tags: python, r, machine-learning, scikit-learn

This was asked about a different package elsewhere, but is there a way in Scikit Learn to include all variables or all variables minus some specified number like in R?

To give an example of what I mean, say I have a regression y = x1 + x2 + x3 + x4. In R I can evaluate this regression by running:

```
result = lm(y ~ ., data=DF)
summary(result)
```

I would have to imagine there's a similar way to condense formulas in Python since writing out all the variables for larger data sets would be kind of silly.

Comment: I don't believe so, here is an example with sklearn [here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/linear_model/plot_ols.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-linear-model-plot-ols-py)

Comment: @lmo I tagged it with both as I figured there's likely to be overlap between R users and Scikit users.

Comment: @114 what exactly are you working with? Can you give a toy example?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I don't actually have a data set that runs into the problem above right now but I could easily imagine a csv with 20000 rows and 200 features where inputting each variable name would be very tedious. I guess the way to do this in Python is to use pandas to get a list using something like `list(my_dataframe.columns.values)` and feeding that into the model somehow?

Comment: NO. You use `my_dataframe.values` Sklearn usually expects some sort of `numpy` matrix. Again, give me an example of what you are doing, because  I've used R and `sklearn` and i've never really missed the "formulas" from R. I think `statsmodels. If you like formulas, for regression, you can use [`statsmodels`](http://statsmodels.sourceforge.net/0.6.0/examples/notebooks/generated/formulas.html)

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga My mistake. But so I guess my updated question would be, what's the best way to feed that list into a Scikit model as a list of dependent variables?

Comment: @114 You don't feed sklearn models a list of dependent variables, you pass it some sort of matrix, usually. See my previous comment, though, if you really want to work with formulas. But in `sklearn` you usually have some `numpy` data structure, and `X`, and some sort of lable `y`, and you use `model.fit(X,y)` So give an example or else I'm confused exactly about what you are referring to.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga I think that actually answers my question, I was approaching this the wrong way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We may try the following workaround (let's use `iris` dataset and the label `species` as numeric and fit a linear regression model to see how to use all the independent predictors both in `R` and `python sklearn`):

**In R**

```
summary(lm(as.numeric(Species)~., iris))[c('coefficients', 'r.squared')]

$coefficients
                Estimate Std. Error   t value     Pr(>|t|)
(Intercept)   1.18649525 0.20484104  5.792273 4.150495e-08
Sepal.Length -0.11190585 0.05764674 -1.941235 5.416918e-02
Sepal.Width  -0.04007949 0.05968881 -0.671474 5.029869e-01
Petal.Length  0.22864503 0.05685036  4.021874 9.255215e-05
Petal.Width   0.60925205 0.09445750  6.450013 1.564180e-09

$r.squared
[1] 0.9303939
```

**In Python (sklearn with pasty)**

```
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
import pandas as pd
from patsy import dmatrices

iris = load_iris()
names = [f_name.replace(" ", "_").strip("_(cm)") for f_name in iris.feature_names]
iris_df = pd.DataFrame(iris.data, columns=names)
iris_df['species'] = iris.target

# pasty does not support '.' at least in windows python 2.7, so here is the workaround 
y, X = dmatrices('species ~ ' + '+'.join(iris_df.columns - ['species']),
                  iris_df, return_type="dataframe")

from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
model = LinearRegression()
model.fit(X, y)

print model.score(X,y)
# 0.930422367533

print model.intercept_, model.coef_
# [ 0.19208399] [[0.22700138  0.60989412 -0.10974146 -0.04424045]]
```

As we can see the models learnt in `R` and `Python` with `pasty` are similar (the order of the coefficients are different).

Comment: `statsmodels` supports `patsy` forumals natively... might be worth mentioning... http://statsmodels.sourceforge.net/0.6.0/examples/notebooks/generated/formulas.html

Answer (score 2):

> is there a way in Scikit Learn to include all variables or all variables minus some specified number?

Yes, with sklearn + pandas, to fit using all variables except one, and use that one as the label, you can do simply

```
model.fit(df.drop('y', axis=1), df['y'])
```

And this would work for most `sklearn` models.

This would be the `pandas`+`sklearn` equivalent of R's `~`and `-` notation, if not using `pasty`.

To exclude multiple variables, you can do

```
df.drop(['v1', 'v2'], axis=1)
```